# Web Application Speed Performance

Tags: performance, reactjs, deployment, webpack

I'm using React and bundle with Webpack to create my web application. 
My simple question is:

My bundling file is only about ~4.5mb, but my overall repo is ~20mb because of pictures and other assets. My question is does the performance(first opening up pages) of application only affected by my bundle size? or the whole repo?

And Also, what's considered an TOO large of repo or bundling? for average enterprise production application?

Comment: What kind of application are you talking about? A web page using react? How does "first opening up pages" happen?

Comment: I guss only bundle size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your production app will probably use is what you generate inside the `build` directory. Sometimes this is only a `bundle.js` file (the images and styles will be inside), other times you can split the `bundle.js` file's images and styles in different files, so you would have to include that. It all depends on your setup.

**4.5mb** is not too much, although it will depend on your server performance too. It is completely normal if it contains all the dependencies. If you need to load some pages faster than the rest, you can split the bundle in multiple files so some parts of your app will not require all the bundle files. This is called code-splitting. You read more about it [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/).

Normally you will want some simple landing pages to load faster, and it would depend if your website is the mainly used by mobile phones (worse network connections) or laptops (normally using Wifi).